# openpyxl concat three dataframes horizonally

Tags: python, dataframe, openpyxl

I am using `openpyxl` to edit three `dataframes`, `df1, df2, df3` (If it is necessary, we can also regard as three excels independently):

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [[1, 1],[1,1]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, index = ['I1a','I1b'], columns=['v1a', 'v1b'])
df1.index.name='I1'

data2 = [[2, 2,2,2],[2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index = ['I2a','I2b','I2c','I2d'], columns=['v2a','v2b','v2c','v2d'])
df2.index.name='I2'

data3 = [['a', 'b',3,3],['a','c',3,3],['b','c',3,3],['c','d',3,3]]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns=['v3a','v3b','v3c','v3d'])
df3 = df3.groupby(['v3a','v3b']).first()
```

[image]

Here df3 is `multiindex`. How to concat them into one excel horizontally (each dataframe start at the same line) as following:

[image]

Here we will regard index as a column and for `multiindex`, we keep the first level hidden.

Comment: Does "df1", "df2", "df3" appear in your cells? Does each dataframe start at the same line?

Comment: pls ingore "df1", "df2", "df3". Yes, each dataframe start at the same line.

Comment: @Corralien pls see my update for more detail

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

IIUC:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), df3.reset_index()], axis=1)

    I1  v1a  v1b   I2  v2a  v2b  v2c  v2d v3a v3b  v3c  v3d
0  I1a  1.0  1.0  I2a    2    2    2    2   a   b    3    3
1  I1b  1.0  1.0  I2b    2    2    2    2   a   c    3    3
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  I2c    2    2    2    2   b   c    3    3
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  I2d    2    2    2    2   c   d    3    3
```

---

**Old answer**

Assuming you know the start row, you can use `pandas` to remove extra columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx', header=0, skiprows=3).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: pls see my update for more detail

Comment: for IIUC, the only problem how to hide the first level of multiindex, say the 'a' in second row should be hide and I have asked a separated question of keep the first level of multiindex hidden here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72327581/pandas-multiindex-convert-multiindex-to-a-column-and-keep-the-first-level-hidde

Comment: so you think it is better to deal with within dataframe rather than concat in openpyxl as three excels?